# Is there any consistency to the swords Finn wields?

Tags: weapon, adventure-time

Whilst watching one of the Adventure time, season three episodes, I recognised that Finn had a pretty cool sword I thought I'd never seen before. I thought to myself:

> My what a cool sword! The show creators must just add random swords to the show!

It looked like this

[image]

But is that true? Does Finn just get a new sword every episode or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, he received *that* sword in '[Mystery Train](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_Train)', and fans have dubbed it the 'Root Sword'.

There is in fact a lot of consistency in the swords Finn wields, far more than you might expect form a normal 'kid's' show. The Adventure time wikia has an entire page on [Finn's Swords](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Finn%27s_swords).

Here is a picture of the ones he regularly uses:

[image: Finn's Standard set of swords]

From Left to right:

1. Finn's Original Golden Sword
2. A 4D version of the golden sword
3. The 'Root sword'
4. The Demon Sword

Comment: It seems to be a bit more consistent now since they received the sword from their dad in ["Dad's Dungeon"](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Dad%27s_Dungeon).

Comment: @TerranceShaw I've not seen that one yet...

Comment: It's actually the demon sword you linked.

Comment: Also notice that each previous sword is destroyed before being replaced.  The Gold Sword was destroyed upon being turned into the 4D Sword and then collapsed, the Root Sword I believe was shattered at some point, the Demon Blood sword was taken back by the demon that their Dad slayed, and most recently, the Grass Blade was destroyed(?).